# How to handle many users and their customers in Ruby on Rails

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, relationship

Actually I know 2 ways to handle many users with their own customers data. This data should only be available to themself.

On way would be to set the relation in the models.

User model

```
has_many :customers
```

customers model

```
belongs_to :user
```

And then I have to add a user_id column to get the belonging data.

The second way would be to setup an extra table where I set the user_id with the customer_id. Something like this:

```
create_table "users_customers", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "customer_id"
  end
```

What is the better way to achieve my requirements. Or is there even a much better way?

Edit Requirements: Many user with only to themself accessible customers.

Comment: Those are different. The second allows a costumer to belong to more than one user, while the first doesn't. You ask "what's the better way to achieve my requirements", but you don't specify what your requirements are.

Comment: edited... Many user with only to themself accessible customers.

Comment: Then the former is what you need. I would reply as an answer, but MrTheWalrus gave a great answer already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each Customer is going to belong to only one User, there's no reason to do anything other than the standard `has_many`/`belongs_to` association.

Join tables (like `users_customers`) are really only useful in one of two cases:

First, if you actually have a many-to-many relationship - one user has many customers, but a customer can also belong to many users.

Second, when you want to store data not about the user or the customer, but about the *relationship* between them, in which case that data might be placed in the join table. This second case is very rare for the basic one-to-many relationship, because all such data could be just as easily stored in the Customer record. It's much more common in conjunction with the first case, because with a many-to-many, there can be data that differs between different associated users to the same customer (for instance).